# How to program some XPath functions using Java Design Patterns

Tags: java, design-patterns, xpath

I need your help and your experience to realize the best java code using Design Patterns.
I must write some custom XPath functions that can:

1. Load a DOM document (I can use a mock object);
2. Check the validity of an user XPath expression;
3. Find and return the DOM node that satisfy the user expression.

I must evaluate only absolute expressions ( /... ) that can contain the path expression " .. " and predicates, embedded in square brackets, regarding attributes or leaf nodes, for examples:

```
/com/university/student/../exam
/com/university/exam[@tt = 'poo']/vote   
/com/university/student/number[. = '1234']
```

I'll use the Composite pattern for the first step, the Chain of Resonsibility for the second step and a Visitor for the third step but I am not sure that this can be the best way to do this.
Can Chain of Resonsibility be usefull to check the validity? 
All suggestions are welcome, thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: I assume this is homework. 2 and 3 are part of standard DOM Level 3 XPath

Comment: @Alejandro This was my exam. A desktop application in Java using a frammework of Dependency Injection

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it a bit ... overcomplicated?

1. Create a DOM object for some XML input
2. Compile the user input - XPath will complain if it is not valid (XPathExpressionException)
3. Evalute the expression with the DOM object

Sample:

```
// #1 load document
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
dbf.setValidating(false);
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = db.parse(file);

// #2 - validate expression
XPathFactory factory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xpath = factory.newXPath();
XPathExpression expr = null;
try {
  XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile(getExpression());
} catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
   // ... handle & return <- invalid expression
}

// #3 evaluate expression
String result = expr.evaluate(doc);
```

Comment: At first I would express gratitude for the interest. Yes, I know it is very tricky. But if you want to separate the data from the operation you must change the code. The Design Patterns guidelines says that you must separate the data and the operation upon data. I think that I must use more than a Factory...

Comment: What is "Design Patterns guidelines"? Which data do you want or need to separate from what operation?

Comment: @Andreas_D I need to separate the data of the concept from the operations that act on that concept. What the system is from what the system does. This opens the door for many different scenarios, in which I can change the behavior of the system by using different behavior classes. These behavior classes can also be reusable for different data classes. Many patterns address this problem, like Visitor, Command, Strategy, or Observer. This is a Design Pattern guideline example.

Comment: @Andreas_D We can define a Pettern as **guideline**, or something that repeats. Now the definition of design pattern becomes creating something in mind that repeats or in other words capturing design ideas as a "pattern" to the problems.

Comment: @Andy - don't get me wrong, I now the GoF patterns pretty well, but we *usually* start with a design and then we *see* the patterns. To me, it looks like you want to do it vice versa - you have s bag of patterns and want to implement as many as possible. OK for training but questionable for production code.

Comment: This was an exam ;) Thank you for the reply!